# Рейтинг? Чи ступінь?

Tags: вживання-слів

Останнім часом намагаюся пильнувати свою українську. Почитав і зрозумів, що rating = ступінь. Згодні чи я не правий?

Для прикладу:

- Рейтинг кандидатів - Ступені кандидатів
- Сортувати за рейтингом - Сортувати за ступенем

Чи справді можна використовувати це слово у вказаних вище прикладах? Мені до вподоби.
Дякую усім, хто відгукнеться.

Comment: можете, будь ласка, уточнити, як саме ви зрозуміли, що rating = ступінь?

Comment: У вікіпедії написано: "Ступінь — порівняльна величина, що характеризує розмір, інтенсивність чого-небудь, міра вияву чого-небудь." По суті те саме, що й "Rate - a measure, quantity, or frequency, typically one measured against some other quantity or measure." в перекладачі від Ґуґла. Закінчення ing додає певну тривалість дії вимірювання чи якось так. Пограв словами, наче все влаштовує.

Comment: Коли я чую "ступінь кандидата", мені згадується науковий ступінь, а не міра популярності.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово *[ступінь](http://sum.in.ua/s/stupinj)* уживають для позначення того, наскільки далеко зайшов якийсь процес (*ступінь розвитку, деградації, забруднення, окиснення* тощо) або наскільки виражена якась характеристика (*ступінь свободи, ризику, довіри, надійності* тощо). Причому для характеристик зазвичай використовують таких, що не виражається числами (наприклад, ніхто не каже *ступінь швидкості, відстані, ваги, вартості* тощо; тобто це слово, на мій погляд, «очислює» характеристику, роблячи з більш якісної характиристики більш кількісну, тому для кількісних нема сенсу застосовувати). Це моя власна інтерпретація тих значень із «Словника української мови», які більш-менш підходять; є й інші значення слова, але вони, по-моєму, зовсім не підходять до оговорюваного контексту. Є ще таке слово *міра*, що частково подібне за значенням: *міра інтенсивності, надійності, забруднення* тощо.

Слово *[рейтинг](http://sum.in.ua/f/rejtyngh)* у «Вільному тлумачному словнику» означують приблизно так: (1) оцінка успішності когось чи чогось [я б ще до цього додав — за якоюсь шкалою]: *рейтинг країни*, *рейтинг кандидата* тощо; (2) список чогось/когось, упорядкований за певною оцінкою: *рейтинг тенісисток*, *рейтинг країн* тощо. Слід зазначити, що «Вільному тлумачному словнику» не є офіційно виданим словником (його не роблять під егідою якогось наукового товариства, він не зазначає редакторів/укладачів і т.ін.). Але в цьому випадку його тлумачення видаються мені доволі влучними (хоч я їх і дещо вточнив у переказі).

*Рейтинг кандитата* — це *міра (ступінь) успішності (чи якоїсь іншої характеристики) кандидата*, я б сказав так. Але я не бачу підстав застосовувати слово *ступінь* до самого *кандидата*, адже **кандидат не є ані процесом, ані характеристикою**.

---

Є ще таке слово — *рівень*. Його застосовують до явищ (*рівень безробіття, шуму, радіації, життя* тощо), але фактично його можна застосовувати й до людей: *покажи мені свій рівень, його рівень вищий за твій* — можливо, це переносне значення або тут маються на увазі якісь додаткові слова (*рівень підготовки*, *інтелектуальний рівень*, *фізичний рівень*), але так кажуть.

Однак це слово я мушу визнати неповним замінником слова *рейтинг* теж. Бо слово *рейтинг* передбачає певну **оціностість** (рейтинг тенісистки, кандидата тощо — це не обов'язково її/його об'єктивний рівень, це лише чиясь, можливо справедлива, а можливо, й несправедлива, оцінка). Водночас *рівень* радше натякає на об'єктивність, ніж на суб'єктивність.

Comment: Проблема в тому, що слова рейтинг не існує в українській мови. Чи обов'язково його вводити в українську мову через неосвіченість людей, що роблять переклад з англійської мови?